# How to copy a directory over the docker cp?

Tags: linux, docker, shell, ubuntu, docker-copy

I want to copy a directory from the host to a container, but I couldn't use the following command:

```
$ docker cp -r <a-dir> <a-container-ID>:/destination/path
unknown shorthand flag: 'r' in -r
```

With `scp -r` shell command I can do it, so I expected the same with `docker cp -r`.

How do I overcome it without using make a compress `.tar` file and the extraction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quoting the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp):

> The `cp` command behaves like the Unix `cp -a` command in that directories are copied recursively with permissions preserved if possible.
>
> -- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/#extended-description

So `docker cp` doesn't have nor need a `-r` flag. Just omit it. Like this:

```
# Create a directory and put two files in it
$ mkdir testdir && touch testdir/aaa testdir/bbb

# Make sure files are there
$ ls -la testdir
total 384
drwxr-xr-x 1 jannisbaratheon 197121 0 paź 10 15:15 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 jannisbaratheon 197121 0 paź 10 15:15 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 jannisbaratheon 197121 0 paź 10 15:15 aaa
-rw-r--r-- 1 jannisbaratheon 197121 0 paź 10 15:15 bbb

# Create container and fetch its ID
$ export CONTAINER_ID=`docker run -di alpine:3.8 sh`

# Make sure the target directory does not exist
$ docker exec "$CONTAINER_ID" sh -c 'ls -la /containertestdir'
ls: /containertestdir: No such file or directory

# Copy the files with 'docker cp'
$ docker cp testdir "$CONTAINER_ID":/containertestdir

# Verify the files were copied by running 'ls -la' in the container
$ docker exec "$CONTAINER_ID" sh -c 'ls -la /containertestdir'
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Oct 10 13:15 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Oct 10 13:15 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Oct 10 13:15 aaa
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Oct 10 13:15 bbb
```

Comment: Thanks for complete explanation +1

Answer (score 3):

It's recursive by default. It will copy whatever you point the command at, to wherever the destination is on the container.

No need to specify recursive.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy a directory like this:

```
docker cp /tmp/test mydocker:/tmp/test
```